# Bitcoin Core Wallet - Really Anonymous?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, privacy

how does one remain truly anonymous on bitcoin network? Say, for example, if one use the bitcoin core as its wallet, while sending one's first transaction, will his/her IP be somehow revealed at that instance? Has anyone tried to run bitcoin core in a VPN/TOR setting or environment?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 1):

> Say, for example, if one use the bitcoin core as its wallet, while sending one's first transaction, will his/her IP be somehow revealed at that instance?

In theory, it is possible, but in practice, no. IP addresses are not in transactions or blocks in any way.

> Has anyone tried to run bitcoin core in a VPN/TOR setting or environment?

Yes. Bitcoin Core has options for using the TOR SOCKS5 proxy and has had this capability for a long time.

Comment: Note that IP address is not the only thing to be concerned about when it comes to anonymity.  Regardless of what IP address is used to broadcast a transaction, you have to hide where the coins you are spending came from.  That is probably the more important part of concealing your identity on the Bitcoin network.

Answer (score 0):

The IP will be revealed to the supernodes or nodes you are directly connected to and if they are recording IP secretly,
I remember blockchain.info storing that data in early days 
You can actually create raw transaction and broadcast it through some service accessed privately, Its the best measure or transfer funds to an online service you can trust

Comment: thanks! By that, it implies that true anonymity is not possible? Nathan Aw

Comment: it is , but with careful measures like bypassing your IP because its a necessary evil in computing
Please upvote if you found this answer helpful